# How to Export Data Using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I receive six to ten emails everyday with following data, which I am trying to extract from outlook 2010 to Excel sheet using VBA.

Care:

```
SVL:    66%
ASA:    78
NCF:    10076
NCO:    10403
NCH:    8741
VAR:    3%
AHTF:   644
AHT:    614
```

Retention:

```
SVL:    82%
ASA:    16
NCF:    1308
NCO:    1240
NCH:    1179
VAR:    -5%
AHTF:   817
AHT:    797
```

I wanted to extract **Care** data in one row and **Retention** data in second.

Here is the code i am using...

```
Sub Stats()
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim vText As Variant
Dim sText As String
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim rCount As Long
Dim bXStarted As Boolean
Const strPath As String = "Y:\Fido_Stats.xlsx" 'the path of the workbook

If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    bXStarted = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0
'Open the workbook to input the data
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Process each selected record
 rCount = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    sText = olItem.Body
    vText = Split(sText, Chr(13))
    'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
     rCount = rCount + 1
    'Check each line of text in the message body
    For i = UBound(vText) To 0 Step -1

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Care:") = 0 Then

      If InStr(1, vText(i), "SVL:") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("B2") = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If

        If InStr(1, vText(i), "ASA:") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("C2") = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If

        If InStr(1, vText(i), "NCF:") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("D2") = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If

        If InStr(1, vText(i), "NCO:") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("E2") = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If

        If InStr(1, vText(i), "NCH:") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("F2") = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If

        If InStr(1, vText(i), "VAR:") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("G2") = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If

        If InStr(1, vText(i), "AHTF:") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("H2") = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If

        If InStr(1, vText(i), "AHT:") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("I2") = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Retention:") = 0 Then

      If InStr(1, vText(i), "SVL:") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("B3") = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If

        If InStr(1, vText(i), "ASA:") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("C3") = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If

        If InStr(1, vText(i), "NCF:") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("D3") = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If

        If InStr(1, vText(i), "NCO:") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("E3") = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If

        If InStr(1, vText(i), "NCH:") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("F3") = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If

        If InStr(1, vText(i), "VAR:") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("G3") = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If

        If InStr(1, vText(i), "AHTF:") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("H3") = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If

        If InStr(1, vText(i), "AHT:") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("I3") = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If
    End If


    Next i
    xlWB.Save
Next olItem
xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
If bXStarted Then
    xlApp.Quit
End If
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set olItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice and all, but what is the question?

Comment: Use the `split` command using `vblf` as the delimiter to split the text to an array. Then you can stream this out to a text file. Unfortunately you haven't given us very much information to go on or shown us the code you have built so far so we can't fix it for you. I mean where would you want the commas? I can make assumptions but it would be better if you showed us what you have done so far. Edit: Just saw your new formatting, is that exactly how it looks in the email?

Comment: yes Dan, i am new to this forum but i have the code which runs fine but it did not seperate Care data and Retention data

Comment: where can i show my code to you with actual Excel output?

Comment: Just edit the original question and plop it in there. Before you copy it from the VBE, highlight it all and press tab once, this will indent it and then when you paste it in here it will automatically be posted as code. SO is not a "normal" code forum, its more tailored to being a knowledge base and to steering people to get the answer themselves as opposed to just giving it. some people get pretty over involved in this concept hence why you were down voted, I will give you an up vote to balance it out but try to always structure your questions so we don't need to ask for more information.

Comment: As for the Excel output, I don't think we will need that really, it's just a standard CSV right? I assume you need each entry on a seperate line like whats posted in your original post?

Comment: I need Headings like "SLV", "ASA" on top than underneath i need both data.

Comment: OK, I will take a look tomorrow for you but my initial thought is use the split command to split the string out to an array, you can then poll the array and output to a csv very easily. You can avoid a lot of your code by joining back the array using a comma, you will need to put a few smarts in there to determine where to start and stop obviously but it should be quite quick. Here is an example of what I mean that you can run in the debug window (ctrl-g) `?join(Array("Hello","World","!!!!!"),",")` if you are still stuck when I get in tomorrow I will post an answer for you.

Comment: Or you can loop the array twice, once on split(arrayelement,":")(0) (your headings) then again on split(arrayelement,":")(1) (your data) outputting that to a string as you go, it's less efficient than a join but I don't think you will have a choice due to the construct of your data.

Comment: Thanks Dan for all your help.